# Alternatives to calling a __global__ function from within a __global__ function?

Tags: cuda

I have some code which is useful enough to merit being its own kernel and is run independently. On the other hand, I have another piece of code which uses the first one as a phase in a large algorithm. Thus I would like both to be invoke the first function both via a kernel launch both as a simple devsion.

Now, you cant just call a `__global__` function from another `__global__` function; and you're not allowed to mark a function as `__global__` `__device__` (which is really too bad, I would have expected that to be possible). So how *can you* make that function call?

Comment: @talonmies: Done.

Comment: It's not done, because the assumptions are incorrect. You CAN just call `__global__` from `__global__` starting with CC 3.5 (Kepler). Even recursively ;). The feature is called [dynamic parallelism](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism)

Comment: @Drop: But I don't mean a launch of a subgrid, just a regular function call.

Comment: This sentence does not make sense to me, I would suggest rephrasing to clarify the question: "Thus I would like both to be invoke the first function both via a kernel launch both as a simple devsion."

Answer (score 2):

My workaround is:

```
namespace detail {
    __device__ void foo(int) { /* ... */ }
} // namespace detail

__global__ void foo(int x) { detail::foo(x); }
__global__ void bar(int x) { detail::foo(baz(x));  }
```

which works, but has a dummy wrapper and you need to duplicate the function header, which is sometimes tedious to do, so I don't like this approach all that much.